# Comparar 2 huellas digitales usando SQL y C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, biometrico

Buen día tengo una aplicación que encentro en Internet, y la adapte a mis necesidades, solamente he logrado hacer que los datos sean capturado, he utilizado Digital persona SDK 1.6.1, tengo un lector de huella: digital persona 4500u.

En mi base de datos los almaceno de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en mi código las guardo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
            Enroller.Template.Serialize(fingerprintData);
            fingerprintData.Position = 0;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);
            try
            {
                /*if (User.id == 0)
                    User.id = dbinfo.compare(User.Login, User.Pass);
                dact_id = dbinfo.InsertFingSample(btarr);
                dbinfo.InsertFinger(User.id, GetFingNum(), dact_id);*/

                SqlCommand vQuery = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Huellas VALUES (CONVERT(varbinary(15),@Imagen))", cadena);
              
                vQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", bytes);
                SqlParameter[] param2 = { new SqlParameter("@Imagen", SqlDbType.VarBinary) };

                param2[0].Value = bytes;


                cadena.Open();
                var tres= vQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cadena.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No" + ex.Message);
            }
              
        }
```

Y mi comparación es la siguiente:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MemoryStream fingerprintData = new MemoryStream();
            Enroller.Template.Serialize(fingerprintData);
            fingerprintData.Position = 0;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fingerprintData);
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fingerprintData.Length);
            try
            {
                /*if (User.id == 0)
                    User.id = dbinfo.compare(User.Login, User.Pass);
                dact_id = dbinfo.InsertFingSample(btarr);
                dbinfo.InsertFinger(User.id, GetFingNum(), dact_id);*/

                SqlCommand vQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(15), Huella,1) as Huellas from Huellas where CONVERT(varchar(40), Huella,1) like '%@Imagen%'", cadena);
                vQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen",bytes);
                

                cadena.Open();
                var reader = vQuery.ExecuteReader();
            
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ya existe");
                    cadena.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Existe");

                    cadena.Close();
                    
                    try
                    {

                        
                        vQuery = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Huellas VALUES (CONVERT(varbinary(15),@Imagen))", cadena);
                        vQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", bytes);
                        SqlParameter[] param3 = { new SqlParameter("@Imagen", SqlDbType.VarBinary) };

                        param3[0].Value = bytes;


                        cadena.Open();
                        vQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cadena.Close();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

lo que pasa es que aunque ponga el mismo dedo siempre me dice que no existe, pero al consultar en la base de datos me muestra registros iguales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede decirme en que estoy mal al momento de comparar. Porque supongo que ahi esta el problema. Ya que sigue insertando aunque ya exista.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿La tabla solo contiene un campo?¿Puedes agregar la definición completa?

Comment: Asi es solamente tiene un campo que es el de Huella. Saludos.

Comment: pero si ingresas el mismo dedo y devuelve que ya existe, eso es correcto

Comment: Perdón Leandro, ya lo corregi.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la pregunta tiene bastante tiempo, comento mis observaciones que le pueden servir a alguien.

Veo varios problemas en tu código, uno de ellos es que al realizar la consulta estas utilizando `where CONVERT(varchar(40), Huella,1) like '%@Imagen%'` lo que significa que estas acortando el campo a una cadena de 40 caracteres, pero el valor que le pasas al `like` son bytes y contiene todos los bytes de la imagen que normalmente son mas de 40 caracteres (*estas comparando texto con bytes*).

EL otro problema que veo es que al insertar estas recortando a 15 bytes `CONVERT(varbinary(15),@Imagen)`, esto no es necesario, si necesitas guardar la imagen debes pasar todo los bytes, ya que definiste la columna como `varbinary(max)`.

Lo que yo te recomiendo es tener otro campo en la base de datos que te permita saber si ya existe un registro para determinada persona, ya que que si sigues haciendo la comparación con bytes te va a dar mucho problemas y aunque los primeros bytes sean iguales el resto de bytes normalmente cambia, eso te darás cuenta cuando no recortes los datos al insertar.

Otra recomendación es que por el nombre del parámetro veo que lo que guardas de la huella es la imagen, pero para una posterior identificación lo que realmente te sirve son las miniciuas que te devuelve el sdk, que pueden ser definidas por los estandares ISO/IEC 19794 y ANSI/INCITS 378 o el formato propio de Digital Persona. Es recomendable usar los estandares ISO o ANSI por si algún día necesitas usar las huellas con otro SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saber si existe deberias usar el `ExecuteScalar()`

```
cadena.Open();

string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) from Huellas 
                    where CONVERT(varchar(40), Huella,1) like '%@Imagen%'";
SqlCommand vQuery = new SqlCommand(query, cadena);
vQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen",bytes);

int cant = Convert.ToInt32(vQuery.ExecuteScalar());

if (cant > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ya existe");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Existe");
}
```

entonces validas la cantidad de registros que coinciden

Comment: Buena tarde, Leandro tu método me ayudo mucho, pero aun no me funciona porque me sigue mostrando que no existe el registre cuando en la base de datos hay 3, con esas características.

Comment: evaluas que parametro estas enviando por parametro? si pones un breakpoint en el codigo y pasas el mouse sobre bytes, porque no creo que puedas comparar a ese nivel, quizas debas convertir a base64 y aplicar un hash para que se compare de forma efectiva

Comment: ¿Tendrás algún ejemplo de eso que me pudieras proporcionar Leandro?